# Is there an advantage to last-hitting a tower?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I last hit a [tower](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Turret) and destroy it, what rewards (if any) do I receive?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no gameplay benefit for last hitting a tower.

The statistic *is* tracked (and viewable on the tab screen), but it does not matter if you, your lanemate, or the siege minion gets the final hit.

Comment: But, if Purple Caster Minion is the one who gets that final hit...

Comment: Thanks.  While reading, I did find that TF's passive and Ashe's Hawkshot both give bonus gold when last-hitting the tower.  I wonder if other abilities, like Nasus's Siphoning Strike, grow as well?

Comment: Purple Caster Minion needs a nerf.